# Highstock/Highchart cannot set Individual Point color

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working on Highstock, I am trying to set a color to a specific point in "data" in Highstock, like in the [example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-symbols/gray), but I couldn't get it to work, no matter how I set the color, it doesn't show on the graph.

**I have tried the option with Highchart API, it works, but it doesn't work with Highstock.**

[jsfiddle link(what I have tried)](http://jsfiddle.net/Ey666/8/)

Is it because I am using x, y to specify the point? Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985901/cannot-set-individual-point-color-in-series-for-highstock-api-it-works-for-high possible duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highstock has point markers disabled by default. You will need to enable them explicitly as follows:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        marker: {
            enabled: true    
        }
    }
},
```

See more at http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.marker

Comment: Can you share a working example *that uses a `Highcharts.stockChart`*?

Answer (score 12):

If you look to your demo you'll see that using `color` it sets the tooltip color and not the `marker`.

To fix it use marker `fillColor` instead, like the following.

```
data: [
    {x: 1343862840000, y: 4, marker:{ fillColor: 'red'} },
    {x:1343863200000, y:5, marker:{ fillColor: 'green'}}
]
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ey666/4/)

**Update**:
It works on `highstock` see [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ey666/9/) demo.
You have to init it using the right object.
Use `Chart` instead of `StockChart`.

*reference*

- [point marker](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/ref/#point-marker--fillColor)

Comment: thanks for the reply. I just notice it only works for Highchart API, it doesn't work with Highstock, can you help me with Highstock? thanks

Comment: @RicardoLohmann, good catch, can not believe I missed that.  I even tryed `marker:{color...`, but missed the api's `fillcolor`.

Comment: Note that for Highcharts, the `color` option does set the color of the point - [example](http://jsfiddle.net/2nsg7kez/).

Comment: The demo doesn't actually use HighStock. Can you share a demo that uses and actual HighStock chart, e.g. a candlestick chart, with colored markers? If so, please post an answer to the question, rather than editing the question. Thanks!