# Cannot set Individual Point color in Series for Highstock API, it works for Highchart API

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working on Highstock, I am trying to set a color to a specific point in "data" in Highstock, like in the [example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-symbols/gray), its using Highchart API,but I couldn't get it to work with Highstock API, no matter how I set the color, it doesn't show on the graph.

Can someone please help?
[Here is what I have tried so far](http://jsfiddle.net/Ey666/8/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highstock has point markers disabled by default, you will need to enable them explicitly as follows,

```
 plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
                enabled: true    
            }
        }
    },
```

API Reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#point.marker.enabled
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/plotoptions/series-marker/

jsFiddle for your code: http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/nrRDg/