# HIghcharts individual plot point color

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Highstock/Highchart cannot set Individual Point color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976093/highstock-highchart-cannot-set-individual-point-color)

Currently use the addPoint function to update the highcharts graph, certain points need to be highlighted/different color... I can't find a method to do this in the api reference, is it possible?

```
//exampleA - Series arrayId
//exampleB - Point value 
//exampleC when not null would has extra tooltip info, these points need to be a different color.

addPoint: function(exampleA, exampleB, exampleC) 
{
    mcjs.chart.series[exampleA].addPoint({ y: exampleB, exampleC });
}
```

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737409/set-different-colors-for-each-column-in-highcharts/7739047#7739047

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You have the change the `fillColor` attribute inside the `Marker` inside the `Data` Attribute.

The `color` attribute inside `data` did not worked for me.

If you want the a green dot, you can look at [this example I made](http://jsfiddle.net/Lu2w9/).

Answer (score 2):

Yes - color is an option in the options object you are passing to addPoint. Here's the API refernence for [addPoint](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Series.addPoint%28%29), and [here's](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#series.data) the description of the options available to you.

Your code should end up looking more or less like this, if you say wanted a green point -

```
mcjs.chart.series[exampleA].addPoint({ fillColor: "#659355", y: exampleB, exampleC });
```

Right now though the object you're passing doesn't quite look valid - you need to match a key to each value; exampleC has no key.