# Highcharts - Scatter plot single series with multicolor plots (points)

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, scatter-plot, scatter

I am using Highcharts scatter plot chart. How can I create scatter plot of single series with mulitple colors for plots?

[image]

Here all points on the serie are in single color. Need to add different color for each point on scatter plot.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976093/highstock-highchart-cannot-set-individual-point-color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with `plotOptions.series.zoneAxis` [Link](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.zoneAxis) and `serie.zone` [Link](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.zones) options :

Here a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/core972/ohm1Lvcz/)